# Please explain this behavior of With, Block and Module

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Good day,

I'm puzzled a bit with this:

```
In[1]:= f[x_]:=With[{xx=x},f[xx_]:=ff[xx]]
DownValues[f]
f[1]
DownValues[f]
Out[2]= {HoldPattern[f[x_]]:>With[{xx=x},f[xx_]:=ff[xx]]}
Out[4]= {HoldPattern[f[xx_]]:>ff[xx]}
```

The same happens if I use `Block` or `Module` instead of `With`.

I expected that the last `DownValues[f]` will give: `{HoldPattern[f[x_]]:>ff[x]}`. But it does not. Please, explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation of `With`.

> With replaces symbols in expr only when they do not occur as local variables inside scoping constructs.

Module and Block are simply not meant to do it.

**Edit** to elaborate on `Module` and `Block`. `The reason symbol is not replaced, is that it is not being evaluated. Block and Module do not do syntactic replacement operations. Try

```
f[x_] := Block[{xx = x}, f[xx_] = ff[xx]]
```

and then evaluate `f[z]`.

Alternatively, you can execute you initial strategy by first using non-scoping construct:

```
f[x_] := With[{xx = x}, 
  Hold[{f[xx_], ff[xx]}] /. {Hold[{a_, b_}] :> SetDelayed[a, b]}]

In[117]:= DownValues[f]

Out[117]= {HoldPattern[f[x_]] :> 
  With[{xx = x}, 
   Hold[{f[xx_], ff[xx]}] /. {Hold[{a_, b_}] :> (a := b)}]}

In[118]:= f[z]

In[119]:= DownValues[f]

Out[119]= {HoldPattern[f[z_]] :> ff[z]}
```

Comment: Is this right for `Module`? It is not clear from the Documentation.